# How to convert tf-idf to a real number

Tags: python, tf-idf

I want to use tf-idf as a feature in learn-to-rank algorithm. In the train file format, the value of each feature is a float number. However, the tf-idf I get for each row of data is a vector. How can I convert this vector to a unique number? In fact I need `transform_to_float` in the following code.

```
df_train["text"] = df_train['product_description'] + ' ' + df_train['product_title']
corpus = df_train['text'].tolist() 
# print(corpus[:5])
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

df_train['tf_idf'] = transform_to_float(X[df_train.reset_index().index])
```

Comment: _However, the tf-idf I get for each row of data is a vector. How can I convert this vector to a unique number?_ Can you be more specific? Is it a vector containing a single element? Why do you have an import in the middle of your script? Can `vectorizer.fit_transform()` not take the Pandas Series as input directly?